# grape - table read as a constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm using rails 5 and grape for api, I'm trying to create grape endpoint for the table application.

```
module PROJ::API::V2
  class Applications < ::Grape::API
      get '/' do
        authorize! :read, Application
        status 200
        present Application.list(filter_params, current_user), with: Entities::ApplicationList, only_show: params[:only], person_base: true, current_ability: current_ability, user: current_user, nps_details: params[:nps_details]
      end
  end
end
```

I'm getting uninitialized constant PROJ::API::V2::Applications::Application. I tried changing the class name and file name still the same error occurs.

Comment: is other table work? i have use grape in many applications, haven't encounter this kind of problems before.

Comment: Other table like Office in same file work except for the Application table @seaify-Freelancer

Comment: change the `application` name to others, i think `application` is a special name.